# Summary Saved Search

Tags: netsuite

In NetSuite, I have a custom record that has a date field, location, and quantity. I basically want to have a search that groups by location, shows one row with the minimum date and the quantity for that record with the min date.

I also need to use that quantity in a formula for a condition for this search.

I have now is group by Location and minimum of date. My issue is on getting the right value for the qty to show up in my results. Any summary value I can think of doesn't get me what I want. Group will show me 2 rows where there is a 2 records for the same Location but different dates. Sum/count/avg are all obvious issues (though I tried them anyways). Min/Max will give me the min/max of the 2 records regardless of the minimum date.

*Note - there are many more than 2 records. I am using the 2 records as a test case right now for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. For others, here is what I did:

Minimum of date field

Minimum of Qty field. used the "When Order by Field" option to set that to the date field.